# Sync videos recorded from multiple cameras temporarily

Tags: raspicam

I have videos captures using 3 Raspberry Pi cameras with the following timestamps, (each video is recorded for the same amount of time):

```
camera1, camera2, camera3
0.000000,0.000000,0.000000
33.315000,33.315000,33.315000
66.631000,66.632000,66.637000 
...................................
...................................
9486161.970000,9486187.786000,9486187.786000
9486195.285000,9486221.102000,9486221.102000 
9486228.601000,9486254.418000,9486254.418000
```

The problem is each camera clock has its own slewing rate and at the end, the frame difference across the cameras goes up to 25ms in the case of `camera1` compared to the other cameras. (While each of them started at a sub-millisecond difference). This makes tracking the position according to each of the cameras really tough because of a temporal misalignment of frames across the cameras.

The answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541761/displaying-frames-from-2-separate-videos-according-to-timestamps-stored-in-a-tex/36543176#36543176) might have been useful but it changes the sampling rate for the final position estimate generated across the cameras.

My aim is to get the position estimate according to each frame across the cameras. How can the videos be synced so this is possible?